# Best practice for communication between Server and background processes

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web app that exposes an api that I use to control a server. On the same server I have a background process. Periodically the web app needs to inform the background process that something has changed so the process can refresh its information from a database. Right now I have it set up such that the background process is launched in a separate thread (using multiprocessing.Process) in the wsgi script that launches the Django app. This is very convenient for starting/stopping everything easily during development.

I know there are a hundred ways I can skin this particular cat but I'm looking for the most elegant. My hunch is that using a multiprocessing.Queue would be a fantastic way to pass data to the background process. However, I don't know where the queue would live in the Django app. Would I instantiate it in wsgi? If so, how would I pass it to the app? Is there someplace else where it should be created so I can access it in the app views?

I'm curious if anyone has dealt with this challenge before.

**SOLVED:**

Per Aviah's suggestion, this is my solution using a SocketServer in conjunction with a static class member Queue. Works beautifully.

My main startup script on the server:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    scanner = Scanner(API.queue)
    scanner.launch()

    print("Launcing Socket Server...")
    server = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost', settings.PORT), API)
    server.serve_forever()
```

The API class:

```
class API(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    queue = Queue()

    def handle(self):
        data = pickle.loads(self.request.recv(RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE))

        ... bla bla ...

        API.queue.put(settings.SIGNALS.update)
        response = {Comm.response_label: Comm.response.ok}
        self.request.sendall(pickle.dumps(response))
```

The Scanner class:

```
class Scanner:
    def __init__(self, signal_queue):
        self.queue = signal_queue

    def launch(self):
        # Launch the worker thread
        x = Process(target=self.scan)
        x.start()

    def scan(self):
        print("FileScanner started...")

        # Service Loop
        while True:
            try:
                signal = self.queue.get(block=False)
                print("Signal received.")
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

            ... bla bla ...
```

Comment: Did you already look at [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)?

Comment: I did. There's no question that it will work but it seems like a heavy solution. If I could use a queue then I probably wouldn't need much code, or add an additional library, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SocketServer is a simple, independent one line up and running python TCP server. You already have it if you have Python, and you can run it on another thread, locally. When you have loads of work, simply move it to another machine. (it is actually used for the django runserver). 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

Comment: This is great. I didn't know about the SocketServer library. I played around a little and finally figured out a way to use it with a Queue. I've edited the post with my chosen solution. Thanks.